# Youtube DataAPI v3 suddenly stopt working

Tags: javascript, youtube

Im using the YouTube API and now it's not working anymore. 
Did i modified something without knowing, I don't know and I hope someone help me with this.

Error code;

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
```

Loading between the `<head>` tag;

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS FILE

```
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function onYouTubeApiLoad() { 
        gapi.client.setApiKey('MY_MOST_RECENT_API_KEY');
    });
}
function search() {
    var q = $('#input').val();
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: q    
    });
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
function showResponse(response) {
    var items = response.items;
    console.log(items);
}
```

*"yes variable `q` return the correct keyword"*

Comment: Where is the onSearchResponse variable defined that you pass to request.execute() ?

Comment: 2 lines down after the `request.execute(onSearchResponse);` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was trying to find a variable, wasn't looking for functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>`

after your `search.js`